# Changing Redshift sort key doesn't change query time

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have two tables with the same data, but with different sort key(invoice_id and contract_id).

Running the same query on two tables shows the same timing:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE contract_id = 1111;
```

I expected that querying the table with contract_id sort key should be much faster, but that is not true. What is wrong in that case?

UPDATE:

Query: `select count(*) from table_name where contract_id = 104416;`

explain for table with sort key diff from contract_id:

```
XN Aggregate  (cost=263655.29..263655.29 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  XN Seq Scan on table_name  (cost=0.00..235162.62 rows=11397065 width=0)
        Filter: (contract_id = 104416)
```

explain for table with sort key contract_id:

```
XN Aggregate  (cost=153835.56..153835.56 rows=1 width=0)
->  XN Seq Scan on table_name  (cost=0.00..128196.29 rows=10255704 width=0)
        Filter: (contract_id = 104416)
```

Comment: Do you see any differences if you run an `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` on the two different tables?

Comment: @Schepo no, plan is the same.

Comment: I think that's the answer, then. The sort key affects the way the data is physically arranged, but with that SELECT statement Redshift still has to do the exact same amount of work for both tables - i.e. query the _entire_ table to find all the rows which match the WHERE clause

Comment: How many rows are in the table, and how many have that particular `contract_id`? Does it behave better if you only retrieve a _subset_ of the columns instead of `SELECT *`? Does the table need a `VACUUM`?

Comment: How long does the query take? Are we talking 2 seconds or 20 seconds?

Comment: You on't say what the actual time was, but with 18MM rows in the table I'd expect it to be very low in either case. Depending on how many nodes are in your cluster, it could be that there are only one or two blocks per node containing this column. Which means that the overhead of query planning and distribution could be larger than the actual query time. And, as other people mentioned, a `select *` means that you have to access _all_ columns from the table, which means at least one block per column per node.

Comment: If you want a more valid comparison, use `select count(column_id) from TABLE where column_id = SOMETHING`. But beware that it's "more" valid, but might be just as irrelevant. You can also look at the various "STV" tables to see the breakdown of query steps, but with short queries they're also unlikely to give you much information.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Total: 18 813 010, for contract: 10 377 124. Looks like after vacuum I see really small improvement 24 and 23 seconds.

Comment: @kdgregory Added explain for suggested query. Looks like after the vacuum cost is better for contract_id sort key.

Comment: @Schepo after vacuum explain is different. Please have a look at the update in the post.

Comment: I asked for how long the query spent, not the execution plan. You mentioned elsewhere that it was ~20 seconds, which does seem high, with or without sort key. So the logical questions are (1) how many nodes are in the cluster, and (2) what's the load on the cluster while you're running those queries?

Comment: I suspect that most of the time taken for your query is consumed by returning the data from Redshift to the client / query editor. As suggested by @kdgregory, a better test is to query that data, but just return one value. Or, you could wrap your query in a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (your query)`, which will run the query but won't send the data back to the SQL client. This will give a better indication of how long Redshift took to runt the query.

Comment: Odd that "width" is zero.

Answer (score 4):

John Rotenstein's answer is spot on but a few more details to consider.

A SORT KEY that matches the WHERE clause helps by allowing Redshift to excludes blocks of data based on table meta data.  Reading fewer blocks from disk means that the table scan will take less time.

First off make sure that the table is ANALYZEd as this will make sure that the metadata for the table is up to date.  If the metadata is not valid it won't be used to accelerate the table scan.

You can check if the table scan size is being reduced by looking at the stl_scan system table for your query.  The field is_rrscan will be true if the table scan was reduced by metadata and the rows field can be compared to the total number of rows in the table to see how much of the table was excluded in the scan.  This comparison will give you a figure of merit on how effective the use of metadata was on your query.

On the topic of effectiveness of reducing the rows scanned through the use of the sort key: secondly, your table is likely too small to see much gain from sort key.  18M records is not large for Redshift, it is actually fairly small.  The unit of disk read on Redshift is the block and every block is 1MB in size.  The data stored is (usually) compressed and takes up much less space than the raw data.  The amount of compression depends on the variability of the data in the block so there is no hard and fast number to use for compression on a block level.  Experience has shown that it is typical for a single block to contain 250K rows across all data types and more than 500K rows for INTs.  I'd guess that each block on your contract_id column has at least 500K rows.  That mean you need 36 blocks to store this entire column.

Now these blocks are (ideally) spread across all the slices in your cluster.  Assuming you haven't made the distribution key equal to contract_id, this means all of your slices have some of the contract_id value specified in the Where clause.  The number of slices you have in your cluster matters as to how many rows can be excluded from your query's table scan.  If we assume that you are on a minimum (1 node) cluster you have 2 slices and each slice (if distribution is balanced) will have 18 blocks for this column and should be able to reduce table scan significantly.  But even a slightly larger cluster will erode the possible savings significantly.  So if your table is a 4 node dc2.large cluster or bigger there is likely little savings to be gained on a table of this size.

Lastly, distribution of the table matters too.  If your DIST KEY is also contract_id then the requested data will be on only one slice of the cluster and only one slice will do the work.  While this can improve table scan speed it will significantly limit the performance of the query.  In general you should not have distribution keys that are common WHERE clause columns due to this effect.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Querying the table with sort key contract_id and using query 'select contract_id, one_more_column from table where contract_id = 106749;' is_rrscan eq to 'f'(did vacuum and analyse before running query). Do you have any other idea?

Comment: My bad. I was checking second run of the same query(looks like it is cached). I found the first one and is_rrscan is 't', so it is using metadata. Thank you! But what is storage it is 't' for other table as well, with sort key diff from contract_id

Comment: It is 't' when I try to filter by any other column.

Comment: The 't' is just indicating that Redshift performed a range restricted scan not that this provided any meaningful benefit.  Compare the rows scanned to the total rows in the table.  If this ratio is 10% or less then the range restricted scan is highly effective.  If is less than 50% it is fair.  Over 50% the benefit is marginal due to the factors John laid out.  Also your cluster size will impact how effective rr_scan can maximally be on a table this size.

Comment: Total rows scanned for not contract_id sort_key: 3,633,678
Total rows scanned for contract_id sort_key: 3,633,678
Total rows: 18,813,010. Why there is no difference in scanned data?

Comment: Can I ask what the over-arching issue is that prompted a question about sort keys and scan time?  Scan time will be determined by the amount of data that needs to be read from disk and the number of disk interfaces working in parallel.  Cluster size determines the number of disk interfaces.  Scanning fewer blocks (by reducing columns or by rr_scan) determines the amount of data read from disk.  There's limited actions that can be done in these areas but if a broader question is on the table more solutions may be available.

Comment: I just wanted to change sort key to what we are using in our queries and expected to see some difference, but actually don't see it.

Comment: So rr_scan is giving you something (good but not great) but it is about the same independent of which sort key.  This is likely due to some correlation between the 2 possible sort key columns (possible?).  3.6M rows means that there were between 4 and 6 likely read.  If this is a 2 node dc2.large cluster this could be just one block per slice.  If only a few rows are being returned it wouldn't take much correlation to produce this effect.  You can query the block metadata for these columns to get a better picture of the ranges of value per block for contract_id in each sort option.

Comment: Fair enough (reason for asking).  This rr_scan process is both simple and complex.  It is simple because Redshift just looks at the max and min value for contract_id in the metadata and decides which blocks MIGHT be needed.  You can look at the metadata (after vacuum and analyze) to see how this choice is made.  It is complex because deciding which sort key(s) will give the most benefit across all query takes some hard analysis.

Comment: You are right about correlation. I will try to create one more duplicate for that table with any other sort key and check the difference. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand this feature. I have created one more table with sort key as some date column. Result is the same. Total rows scanned is the same and time as well.

Comment: To really understand this you will likely need to review stv_blocklist.  This contains the metadata for the table broken down by slice, column and block.  The key information is minvalue and maxvalue which represent the span of values of each block. Redshift is comparing the WHERE value to this metadata to decide how much of the table needs to be read from disk.  When you change the sort key of the table you are changing the row order and therefor the rows in a block resulting in new min and max values.  Remember that the table needs to be vacuumed and analyzed for these changes to apply.

Comment: Again your table is likely too small to show a lot of difference (depends on cluster size).  Your choice of sort key for the "slow" case will need to make the metadata for  contract_id appear like the value you are looking for can be in any block.  So if you are looking for the highest or lowest value of contract_id (vs. a mid value) then there will be only one block's metadata that will contain this value and sort key cannot matter.  The best way to understand what Redshift is doing is to walk through the process it is doing yourself.

Comment: Bill Weiner Thank for your time and great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Redshift is a columnar data store, meaning that each column is stored separately on disk. Each 1MB block on disk has a Zone Map that identifies the minimum and maximum value of the rows in that block (and each block contains only one column).

Thus, having sorted data means that Redshift can 'skip over' more blocks on the disk. The slowest part of a query is reading from disk, so a SORTKEY on the `contract_id` column should make it faster.

If it is *not* faster, then potential causes could be:

- The table isn't sorted and needs a `VACUUM`
- The number of rows might be so small that it doesn't occupy much disk space, so it ran at the same speed
- Querying all columns ('*') means it has to read lots of columns from disk, so the time saving is negligible (it is rare that a Data Warehouse does a `SELECT *` query -- it is *much* more efficient when selecting only from a subset of columns)
- The column is highly compressed, which means one block of `contact_id` could map to multiple blocks for the other columns, leading to more disk access

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 1. Looks like vacuum changed the execution plan cost. 2. I have ~18M records in the table. 3. Trying to select just 2 columns: contract_id and one more - result is the same. 4. Not sure about this point.